# PHP - Code following header breaking response

Tags: php, xml

An online payment expects an xml as a response. In addition to the response a pdf and an invoice need to be created.

If `actionCreatePdf` or `sendInvoice` are called anywhere before `header` or after the closing `else` bracket the generated invoice is added to the `xml` as well. So there's a bunch of html code in the xml which shouldn't be there.

How can the pdf and invoice be created without interfering with the `xml`?

```
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
                echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
                if ($errorCode == 0) {
                    echo "<crc>{$errorMsg}</crc>";
                    $order = TRUE;
                } else {
                    echo "<crc error_type=\"{$errorType}\" error_code=\"    {$errorCode}\">{$errorMsg}</crc>";
                }   

    $this->actionCreatePdf($payment->id);

    $this->sendInvoice($payment);
```

Comment: What is the task of actionCreatePdf and sendInvoice? Are you trying to output the XML for the payment processing and sending out the invoice via email?

Comment: Yes. The XML is strictly for the service we are using. After it receives it, the user is redirected back to our platform. But since the invoice html is being added to the XML, the payment process stalls and the user is never redirected.

Comment: My invoice was being echoed because there was a `die()` left in its template. So problem solved!